# Break levels in PHP

Tags: php, break

I have this snippet of code and it's working just fine (because in my example that variable really exists in **$arrival_time** so it breaks at about **$k = 10**).

```
$arrival_time = explode(",", $arrival_timeAll[1]);

$sizeOfArrival = sizeof($arrival_time);
$k = -1;
while (++$k < $sizeOfArrival) {
    if ($arrival_time[$k] >= $someVariable) {
            break;
    }
}
```

Isn't that the same as this code? I added the **while(true)** loop and increased the "break level" - so it's now **break 2**, not just **break**. But seems that's an infinite loop. Why?

```
while (true) {
    $arrival_time = explode(",", $arrival_timeAll[1]);

    $sizeOfArrival = sizeof($arrival_time);
    $k = -1;
    while (++$k < $sizeOfArrival) {
        if ($arrival_time[$k] >= $someVariable) {
            break 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Why adding **while(true)**? Because I need to define some more statements (which here aren't neccesary for explanation) if inside while loop doesn't find the matching one (if that "break" in first case, "break 2" in second case doesn't run).

Anyway - why this isn't working?

Comment: Are you sure the `if` statement is really executed (**always**)? You would not notice in your first example and in the second you would be caught in an infinite loop. Instead of this interesting inner while loop construction you could simply use `foreach($arrival_time as $time)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases, the predicate for the inner while loop is never hit, thus the while loop is never executed. As you don't have a break after it, the loop will run forever. This case would be if the array is empty, `0 < 0` is false.

Starting with `$k = -1`, the first time the predicate gets evaluated, `$k` will be `0` as you are using the preincrement operator, for an empty array this will evaluate to false and the code with run infinite. Without the `while(true)` loop this wouldn't cause any problems as you'd just jump straight over it.

Comment: Correct! I overlooked one variable which caused the empty array. Now everything is fine. The code above works. Thanks.